# I need a Android Wifi/bluetooth program for transferring photos taken to another Wifi device, can anybody kindly provide any resources/example code

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

I am trying to write an Android Program to transfer a photo taken on a android phone to a remote device(e.g. another phone or computer) using Wifi or Bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? 
http://www.howtogeek.com/167344/how-to-easily-transfer-files-between-nearby-smartphones/

Comment: Correct,But I thought it could be done using bluetooth or Wifi and any example code if available would be very helpful

Comment: Here you have an example directly from the source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html